# python from mac ports, sublimeREPL dosnt run

Tags: python, sublimetext2, macports, sublimerepl

I use mac ports to install python and many other modules like pygame, numpy, networkx. Codes work well on spyder and IDLE.

But when using sublimeREPL to run codes in python. It says "no module named pygame", like the follows(Sorry I cant post image for short of reputations)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "12.py", line 2, in <module>
     import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```